# Get file metadata from Amazon s3

Tags: xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to figure out how to access the metadata from Amazons3 in Xcode. I found a few examples of code but I am not able to access the S3ObjectMetadatRequest object. Its not even popping up in intellisense. All the other code examples use a lower version of AWS3 sdk for ios. Can anynoe point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wonder if you should be using AWSS3HeadObjectRequest to get the metadata?

Comment: Yes you are right, but im using the AFNetworking AWS3 subclass which has a function called "headObjectWithPath" this returned me all the values i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jarmods amnswer is correct there is an object called AWSS3HeadObjectRequest which i would use, But im using the AFNetworking Subclass called "AFAmazonS3Manager". Its a much easier way to implement all the AWS methods plus it expands upon an already greatly managed Networking system. So to be clear jarmods answer is correct but if you want to use the subclass i decided to use the function is "headObjectWithPath".